# Second RAID hard drive is mirroring first?

Tags: mount, hard-drive

By running the following command, I get the result:

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME    FSTYPE               SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda                          1.8T            
├─sda1                    1004.5K            
├─sda2  linux_raid_member   19.5G            
│ └─md2 ext4                19.5G /          
├─sda3  linux_raid_member    1.8T            
│ └─md3 ext4                 1.8T /home      
└─sda4  swap                 511M [SWAP]     swap-sda4
sdb                          1.8T            
├─sdb1                    1004.5K            
├─sdb2  linux_raid_member   19.5G            
│ └─md2 ext4                19.5G /          
├─sdb3  linux_raid_member    1.8T            
│ └─md3 ext4                 1.8T /home      
└─sdb4  swap                 511M [SWAP]     swap-sdb4
```

Two times 2TB hard drives. This is a RAID setup, though I am not sure what that means.

For some reason the sdb drives doesn't seem to have ever been mounted, or if it has been I don't know how to access it. I don't understand why the mount points are the same?

How can I mount the second drive, sdb?

I've tried:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /media/data
```

it says: mount: /dev/sdb3 already mounted

Comment: It appears that sdb is *mirroring* sda, so that if either of the two drives fails, you'll still have all of your data.  If you want 4 TB total space, you could repartition, reformat, and mount sdb, but you'll lose the safety that RAID provides.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an RAID 1 set-up. This means that the content of both hard disks is mirrored. This is used to prevent data loss because of hardware failures. Your data is available via the devices

- `/dev/md2` → `/`
- `/dev/md3` → `/home`

It looks like a software raid, hence, you might check the status using:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```